# Where can I put a hard drive on my computer?

Tags: hard-drive, connection, case

I have searched up my motherboard and it says 4x SATA slots, so the motherboard is compatible with more hard drives, yet I can't figure out where exactly you would put them in the case. I also tried to look on the internet for my case but I couldn't find it again. I also couldn't figure out if the Cable on the picture [image: Cable on the picture] is able to be connected to a hard drive.

Side View
[image: Side picture of tower]
Front View
[image: front view of tower]

Comment: Take off the other side panel. Chances are there is space in the bottom where the power cable for your GPU is coming from. Your connector is also not a hard drive power connector. Hopefully those connectors are hidden in the area near the PSU, which again should be accessible by removing the other side panel.

Comment: Photos are terrible (angles), your motherboard (*what* motherboard?!), what hard drive you try to add?! If you need adding 2.5/3.5" hard drives it seems you're missing parts to accommodate them.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen The HDD bays are hidden on this case style, see my answer. Usually they have a little assembly that is held in by thumb screws and can be taken out to fit HDDs into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your case would appear to be a Corsair [Carbide Series SPEC-DELTA RGB Tempered Glass](https://www.corsair.com/uk/en/p/pc-cases/cc-9011166-ww/carbide-series-spec-delta-rgb-tempered-glass-mid-tower-atx-gaming-case-black-cc-9011166-ww) case, judging by your image.

In most of the cases where there is a large bar along the bottom it is because that is where the PSU and HDDs are meant to go to isolate them from the rest of the case.

If you remove the panel on the other side of your PC you will see the below area (image taken from that Corsair page):

[image]

The two reddish zones are where you can install two 2.5" HDDs, the purple areas are where 3.5" HDDs can go. There may also be mounting options for 2.5" drives in the purple zone.

To the right of the purple zones will be your power supply. Hopefully there will also be SATA power connectors for HDDs and SSDs. The connector will look something like this:

[image]

You may also need [SATA Data cables](https://www.amazon.co.uk/SATA-3-Cable/s?k=SATA%203%20Cable) to connect them unless you have those already.

You should connect the data cables to the sockets on the right side of your motherboard, or there might be some more of these connectors along the bottom edge of your motherboard. See this image

[image]

In order to remove the side panel there are usually two thumbscrews on the back of the machine, if you undo them then the panel should slide back slightly and then be able to be taken off. They will be in the positions below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, Just one more thing to ask, how could I come about disassembling the back panel as there seems to be no screws or pins or whatever?

Comment: @PanzerIV Added a final image to my answer. You should be able to undo two thumb screws on the back and then the panel will slide back slightly and essentially fall away.

Comment: @PanzerIV added a slightly better image